# Merge child properties in objects with the same key name in ES6?

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I am trying to merge and array nested objects based on the same day of the week in ES6? How can i add in the new object?

see the example below:

```
let opens = {name:"Fri", series: [name: "opens", value: 24]}
let clicks= {name:"Fri", series: [name: "clicks", value: 22]}
let sent= {name:"Fri", series: [name: "sent", value: 22]}

Into {name:"Fri", series: [{name: "opens", value: 24},{name: "opens", value: 24},{[name: "sent", value: 22]}]}
```

Comment: This `[name: "opens", value: 24]` is invalid.

Comment: You seem to have an array that should probably have been an object?

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming a valid object, i.e:**

```
{name:"Fri", series: {name: "opens", value: 24}}
```

You can put the three objects into an array and then execute the function `reduce`.

```js
let opens = {name:"Fri", series: {name: "opens", value: 24}};
let clicks= {name:"Fri", series: {name: "clicks", value: 22}};
let sent= {name:"Fri", series: {name: "sent", value: 22}};

var result = Object.values([opens, clicks, sent].reduce((a, c) => {
  (a[c.name] || (a[c.name] = {name: c.name, series: []})).series.push(c.series);  
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```